gWidgets2RGtk2 problem for newer versions of R

I want to use tReasure tool for a scientific purpose (https://github.com/jinoklee/tReasure). Very important for me to complete my work. However, I couldn't install it because it gave error about "gWidgets2RGtk2".

When I tried to install it in R, it gave:
> Error in library("gWidgets2RGtk2") : 
  there is no package called ‘gWidgets2RGtk2’

Then I used,
> install.packages("gWidgets2RGtk2")

But gave another error:
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gWidgets2RGtk2’ is not available for this version of R

My research says ‘gWidgets2RGtk2’ is removed in the newer versions of R, so installed older versions but still got the same error. So I am back to R version 4.4.2.
My questions is "Is there a way of installing gWidgets2RGtk2 in the R version 4.4.2?"
Ps. I am fairly new to R environment.
Thank you for your help,
Burak

The gWidgets2RGtk2  package was archived in 2021 because one of it's dependencies was orphaned. See how to install archived packages for ways to install that version; but given that it was archived so long ago, it likely won't work with more modern versions of R. It looks like 4.1.2 was current at that time, so you might want to go back and try that. But if you are starting a new project, you should probably find some alternative which is currently supported.

You might try devtools to install it from https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2RGtk2. I think the issue is not this package, but rather the RGTk2 package but that may just be platform dependent, so may still work for you.
